# React Native floating button not working with Flatlist

Tags: react-native, react-native-flatlist

I'm trying to implement a simple screen in which I have a flatlist of items and a floating button which will add some records (like a simple todo list app), the problem is, the floating button was working fine before I added the flatlist, now it seems like the flatlist is hiding the floating button but it is visible though, what should be the problem here? I tried setting `zIndex: 1`, but still the same, not working...

```js
return (
        <View style={styles.container}>
            <View style={styles.headerContainer}>
                // header
            </View>

            <Button title="show addresses" />

            <FloatingButton setModalVisible={setModalVisible} /> // this is not touchable anymore after adding flatlist

            <FlatList
                data={records}
                renderItem={renderItem}
                keyExtractor={(item, index) => `${item.id}${index}`}
                ItemSeparatorComponent={Separator}
            />
        </View>
    );

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
        flex: 1,
        padding: 15,
    },
    headerContainer: {
        flexDirection: 'row',
        alignItems: 'center',
        justifyContent: 'space-between',
    },
    ...
})
```

Floating Action Button Component:

```js
const FloatingButton = ({ setModalVisible }) => {
  const openModal = () => setModalVisible(true)
  return (
    <TouchableOpacity style={styles.container} activeOpacity={0.7} onPress={openModal}>
      <Text style={styles.add}>+</Text>
    </TouchableOpacity>
  )
}
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
        position: 'absolute',
        bottom: 50,
        right: 20,
        height: 50,
        width: 50,
        elevation: 5,
        backgroundColor: 'lightgreen',
        borderRadius: 25,
        alignItems: 'center',
        justifyContent: 'center',
    },
    add: {
        color: 'white',
        fontSize: 26,
    },
});
```

Can someone help me?

Comment: There is a known issue with pressable items within a flatlist. Maybe you can find some help here: https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/14155

Comment: @BaconPancakes HI, as you can see in the code that my flatlist items are not pressable, that is not my need, the floating action button, which is not a part of flatlist, that is not pressable...